# Enable CORS on API Gateway + Lambda Microservice template + DynamoDB

Tags: cors, aws-lambda, microservices, api-gateway

I already enable CORS resource in the API Gateway, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** headers in lamda function (nodejs).

It works for me

```
const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }    
});
```